# Sum dataframe rows and put the result in the next row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    col1    col2      col3    col4
0    A       A_1       8        4
1    A       A_2       2        7
2    A       A_3       5        5
3    A       A_sum
4    B       B_1       9        8
5    B       B_2       6        8
6    B       B_3       5        2
7    B       B_sum
```

I want to sum the row from col3 and col4 that belong to A or B and put the sum in the index 3 and 7 and then have an ouput data frame like this:

```
    col1    col2      col3    col4
0    A       A_1       8        4
1    A       A_2       2        7
2    A       A_3       5        5
3    A       A_sum     15       16
4    B       B_1       9        8
5    B       B_2       6        8
6    B       B_3       5        2
7    B       B_sum     20       18
```

Edited:
Thank you @andrej it worket perfectly with the df like above, but in this one below:

```
    col1    col2      col3    col4
0    A       A_1       8        4
1    A       A_2       NaN      7
2    A       A_3       NaN      5
3    A       A_sum     NaN      NaN
4    B       B_1       9        8
5    B       B_2       6        8
6    B       B_3       5        NaN
7    B       B_sum     NaN      NaN
```

when I try your solution @andrej, it gives me this output:

```
    col1    col2      col3    col4
0    A       A_1       8        4
1    A       A_2       8        7
2    A       A_3       8        5
3    A       A_sum     8        16
4    B       B_1       9        8
5    B       B_2       6        8
6    B       B_3       5        16
7    B       B_sum     20       16
```

Is there a way to have the sum values only for index 3 and 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
# if the empty values aren't NaNs already:
# df = df.replace("", np.nan) 

vals = df.groupby("col1").sum()
df = df.set_index("col1")
df.update(vals, overwrite=False)
print(df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  col1   col2  col3  col4
0    A    A_1   8.0   4.0
1    A    A_2   2.0   7.0
2    A    A_3   5.0   5.0
3    A  A_sum  15.0  16.0
4    B    B_1   9.0   8.0
5    B    B_2   6.0   8.0
6    B    B_3   5.0   2.0
7    B  B_sum  20.0  18.0
```

---

EDIT:

```py
m = ~df.col2.str.contains("_sum")
df.loc[m] = df[m].fillna(0)

vals = df.groupby("col1").sum()
df = df.set_index("col1")
df.update(vals, overwrite=False)
print(df.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  col1   col2  col3  col4
0    A    A_1   8.0   4.0
1    A    A_2   0.0   7.0
2    A    A_3   0.0   5.0
3    A  A_sum   8.0  16.0
4    B    B_1   9.0   8.0
5    B    B_2   6.0   8.0
6    B    B_3   5.0   0.0
7    B  B_sum  20.0  16.0
```

Comment: @ShivamRoy This will group by column "col1" and sum the col3/col4 columns. Then `DataFrame.update()` will update all `NaNs` with this sum according the index/columns (we did `.set_index("col1")` previously)

Comment: @AndrejKesely i Editet my problem, can you check if you can solve this one? And also how to not print that 15.0 but only 15? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndrejKesely, you are a lifesaver.

Comment: @AndrejKesely one more thing, do you have any idea how to print that for example only 8 and not 8.0? I tried int() but when I write df.to_csv(), the numbers still have that ".0"

Comment: @user14073111 You can try `df.loc[:, 'col3':'col4'] = df.loc[:, 'col3':'col4'].astype(int)`